Field extension $L/K$ such that $L$ and $K$ are isomorphic, then the degree of the extension need not be 1?
As above. This is quite confusing for me. If two fields are isomorphic, and one is a subset of the other, how is it that the degree of the extension is not one? Can you give me a counterexample?
EDIT: The full question says

If $K\subseteq L$ is a field extension, then $[L:K]=1$ if and only if $K$ is isomorphic to $L$.

It then goes on to say it's false, not giving further reasoning as to why. If $[L : K]$ = 1 then I think they're equal, so I assumed the other direction was wrong.

Could you please provide the context of your question? I think something is missing.

$F(x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots) / F(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$.  I suspect that if the (algebraic) degree of the extension is finite, it has to be $1$ but I'm not sure of that.

I have edited the question to add the full context. Thank you!

@IgnaciodeMiguel  I think the example Robert gave is the one you look for (and perhaps the only possible way to construct a counterexample). But let see if someone came up with another  eg.

@Tri Another common example is if $k$ is a imperfect field of characteristic $p$, then $k^{1/p}/k$ is a nontrivial extension but $k \simeq k^{1/p}$ abstractly as fields.

@CJDowd Oh I see. This may sound stupid but the assumption that $k$ is imperfect is to guarantee the map $x \mapsto x^p$ is injective, am I correct?

@Tri: Any nontrivial field endomorphism is necessarily injective (the kernel is an ideal!) If the field is perfect, then every element is a $p$-th power, so $k^{1/p}=k$ and you would not get a nontrivial extension. Being imperfect is to guarantee the map is not surjective (hence not an automorphism).

@ArturoMagidin Understood! Thank you so much.

This trick has appeared on the site before. At least here and most likely earlier, but I could not find a definitive duplicate target right away.

The field $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(x)$, the field of rational functions in one variable (the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$), since $\pi^2$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$. Likewise, $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)\cong\mathbb{Q}(x)$.
Setting $K=\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$, we have $K\subseteq L$, $K\cong L$, but $[L:K]=2$. So the "if" clause of the statement does not hold. Note that this is a finite, separable extension (in fact, a Galois extension, since it has degree $2$ in a field that is not of characteristic $2$).
The "only if" statement holds, since $[L:K]=1$ is equivalent to $L=K$, which of course implies $L$ is isomorphic to $K$.
